# Verificar dados de checkbox que tem nomes de variáveis

Tags: php, html, checkbox

Tenho uma rotina em PHP que gera uma lista com dez a quinze nomes, e junto com cada nome gera uma caixa checkbox que deverá ser marcada caso haja a falta ao trabalho daquele nome, caso não haja a falta ao trabalho a caixa não é marcada, e ao final da conferencia, a lista é enviada.

Como receber os nomes dos check box que não foram marcados, uma vez que os nomes de cada check box é a eles atribuídos através de variáveis ?

Observe q é muito fácil receber de um formulário o dado de um checkbox quando ele tem um nome fixo, isso eu sei fazer, observe no código abaixo que os check box não tem nomes fixos,o action "confereescala.php" tem que receber os nomes dos check box não marcados.

```
<form name="" method="Post" action="confereescala.php">
            <ul>
            <?php
            //recebe de outra pagina o nome da equipe de hoje
            $nomeEquipe = $_post['equipe'];

                    // bloco faz a busca na tabela empregados procurando empregados que sejam da equipe que foi enviada
                    $sqa = "SELECT * FROM `empregados` WHERE (`equipe` = '".$nomeEquipe."')  ";
                    $sqb = mysql_query($sqa);
                    $num = mysql_num_rows($sqb);


                // faz o loop imprimindo na tela os nomes encontrados e os checkbox que sao da equipe encontrada
                //observe que cada check box recebe um nome diferente, que é dado pela variavel $empregadosdehoje['nome']
            while ($empregadosdehoje = mysql_fetch_array($sqb);){ ?>


                <li><a><input type="checkbox" size="8" name='<?php echo $empregadosdehoje['nome'] ; ?>'> <?php echo $empregadosdehoje['nome'] ; ?> </a></li>



            <?php } //fecha o while ?>
            <input class="button" type="submit" value="conferencia"/>
            </ul>
            </form>
```

Comment: Na verdade, o checkbox vazio não tem como "passar" valor. O que vc poderia fazer é no arquivo seguinte comparar o que foi marcado com o cadastro no banco, ai extrair os que não foram marcados, entendeu?

Comment: Também daria para vc criar um "input hidden" junto no momento de criar os checkboxes. Ai na página seguinte vc recebe todos hidden, mas ai basta comparar com o checkbox. Acho mais facil esse método.

Comment: Boa tarde Diego,, obrigado pela dica,, eu fiz como vc falou,,, com os campos hidden, foi um tanto trabalhoso mais deu certo,,, abraços,,,

Comment: Se puder marcar a minha resposta como aceita então, agradeço. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Daria para vc criar um *input hidden* junto no momento de criar os checkboxes. Ai na página seguinte vc recebe todos hidden, mas ai basta comparar com o checkbox. Acho mais facil esse método.

```
 <input type="hidden" name="anexoDown" id = "anexoDown">
```